# Apply converter for each item WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in a WPF application. The itemssource for this datagrid is a List consisting of objects of different types. I also have a converter that can convert all objects of different source types into one anonymous object according to certain rules. Is it possible to apply in xaml converter to each element of the itemssource?

This is my code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            List<object> dataSource = new List<object>()
            {
                new BvFile { Name = "file1", Size = 200 },
                new BvFolder { Name = "folder"}
            };

            //lbox.ItemsSource = dataSource;
            dGridTest.ItemsSource = dataSource;
            var bp = 0;
        }
    }

    class BvFolder
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class BvFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
    }

    public class BvElementConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string nameValue = null;
            string sizeValue = null;
            if (value is BvFile)
            {
                BvFile file = value as BvFile;
                nameValue = file.Name;
                sizeValue = file.Size.ToString();
            }

            if (value is BvFolder)
            {
                BvFolder file = value as BvFolder;
                nameValue = file.Name;
                sizeValue = "this is folder";
            }

            return
                new
                {
                    Name = nameValue,
                    Size = sizeValue
                };
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
            <GridSplitter></GridSplitter>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dGridTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False">                
                <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                        Header="Наименование"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Size}"
                                        Header="Размер"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

I tried:

```
                <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="DataContext"
                                Value="{Binding Path=DataContext,                            
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Converter={StaticResource ElementConverter}}">                            
                        </Setter>                       
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

expected:
each datarow will get the converted item

Comment: Usually you would assign the ItemsSource property using data binding instead of the explicit code-behind assignment. Now that you use data binding, you can easily attach a IValueConverter to the Binding. Your converter would get the original IEnumerable of items and can project each item to a new collection.

Comment: Does your converter get hit at all, and if so, I assume `value` is `null`?

Comment: Connor, in my example the converter does not work

Comment: It will be better to put the data normalization into each of the Data Model classes. Consider a base class with some specific implementation at each of the derived classes. With this approach you do not need the converter.

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary to use a converter. add `FallbackValue` to Size column binding:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dGridTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False">                
    <DataGrid.Columns>                    
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="Наименование"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Size, FallbackValue='This is folder'}"
                            Header="Размер"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I would like to know exactly how to apply the converter to the source element.  using a converter or fallbackvalue on columns is not entirely appropriate, since in my real example there are many more columns and the logic in them is more complicated